# $\zeta_n^k$ is primitive if and only if $(k,n) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

Show that for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$:

Is $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then $\zeta_n^k$ is primitive if and only if $(k,n) = 1$.

**I only need the backwards direction:**

$\zeta_n^k$ is primitive $\Rightarrow$ $(k,n) = 1$

Answer (score -1):

First of all notice that $\zeta_n^k$ is of the form
$$
e^{2\pi i\frac kn}
$$
and the hypotesis of being primitive means that $n$ is the smallest (positive) integer such that $(\zeta_n^k)^n=1$. If by contradiction $(k,n)=d>1$ then you can write $k=ad$ and $n=bd$, with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and $a,b\ge1$. Thus
$$
\zeta_n^k=e^{2\pi i\frac {ad}{bd}}=e^{2\pi i\frac d{b}}.
$$
From here we deduce that $(\zeta_n^k)^b=1$ and since $b<n$ (in fact $0\le k\le n-1$) our root cannot be primitive.

Comment: $(3,9)=3$ so whats $a,b$ here? It should be $1 \leq a,b$ but is your argument then still working?

Comment: The key fact is that, since $k\le n-1$ then the common divisor between $k$ and $n$ strictly divides $n$, that is $n=bd$ with both $b$ and $d$ (wlog positive) and $<n$. In your case $k=3$ and $n=9$, thus we can take $b=d=3$ (I have edited $a,b\ge1$ and in this case $a=1$).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:abstract-algebra] and nothing about it suggests that the field in question is a subfield or an extension of $\mathbb{C}$, so an approach which argues on the basis of primitive roots in $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't really answer the question.